# Execute ruby method from command-line

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have the following class in Ruby in the file *test_class.rb*:

```
class TestClass

   def test_verify_one
         # DO SOME
   end

   def test_verify_two
         # DO SOME
   end

end
```

To execute this class I send two parameters to the terminal, ENVIRONMENT and LANGUAGE.

So... to call from terminal I use:

```
ruby test_class.rb ENVIRONMENT LANGUAGE
```

This executes both methods.

I want to execute only one.

I tried the following:

```
ruby -r "test_class.rb" -e "TestClass.test_verify_one" ENVIRONMENT LANGUAGE
```

but it is not working.

Can you help me?

Comment: is the `def self.name_of_method` the problem???

Comment: "This executes both methods" - no, it doesn't, given the code that you show. Nothing is executed here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you were right... that is something that I added to try a new approach. I updated the code.

Comment: Still it won't execute any code.

Comment: What @Sergio means is that, to execute your code, you need to add lines such as the following after your class definition: `t = TestClass.new; t.test_verify_one; t.test_verify_two`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: thanks Cary :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the same folder as `test_class.rb`, run the `ruby` command with the following command syntax:

```
ruby -I . -r "test_class" -e "TestClass.test_verify_one" arg1 arg2
```

Breaking this command down we get:

`-I .`  Include current directory in $LOAD_PATH so we can use `require`

`-r` Require a file named `test_class` within the $LOAD_PATH. This is possible because we included the current directory in our load path above (.rb extension is optional here).

`-e` Same as you've provided, evaluates the following code.

Now, if we call `ARGV` within that method we should get `arg1` and `arg2` on separate lines:

```
#...
def self.test_verify_one
  puts ARGV
end
#...
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony E

Now I am having this issue:

`-e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `test_verify_one' for TestClass:Class (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Did your original question use a class method? In your case it would be `-e TestClass.new.test_verify_one`. Doesn't matter if you use a class or instance method here

Comment: I did @Anthony,

I tried with

`ruby -I . -r "test_class" -e "TestClass.new.test_verify_one" arg1 arg2`

and also with

`ruby -I . -r "test_class" -e "TestClass.new(test_verify_one)" arg1 arg2`

but I get:

`C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/test-unit-3.0.8/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb:400:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
        from -e:1:in `new'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'`

Comment: Your `test_class` filename may be colliding with one of the core classes of ruby. Try rename both your file and class to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your first method to take the variables you're passing to it you need to define your first method to take two variables, like so:

```
class TestClass

    def test_verify_one (var1, var2)
             # DO SOME
       end

       def test_verify_two
             # DO SOME
       end

end
```

You will then need to put a condition into your second which causes it to only execute under the conditions you want it to... or just comment it out if you don't need it at the moment. So, for example, if you only wanted test 2 to fire when variables were not passed in, your code would look something like this:

```
class TestClass

    def test_verify_one (var1, var2)
        # DO SOME
    end

    def test_verify_two (var1, var2)
        if (var1 and var2) defined? nil
        # DO SOME
    end

end
```